# Why doesn't this SQL statement work?

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.user_id = table2.id
AND table1.content = news
AND table1.content_id = 1
```

that wont work. cant u have two "AND" in a sql statement??

//Tomek

Comment: -1 for vague title not in form of a question.  Not enough description of error.

Comment: This is a valid question just worded poorly. Instead of downvoting, why not edit the question to make it a bit easier to understand?

Comment: Not everyone can edit questions - so a downvote is all we have - besides it's a really lame question.

Comment: @Out In Space — I'm guessing he finds it difficult to edit questions without the necessary reputation.

Comment: @Out Into Space, yes, that was the case, I can't edit the question, I gladly would have.  Now that its been edited, i'll gladly take off my downvote.

Comment: @Jeff, I was making a general statement to future downvoters. I hope no offense was taken.

Answer (score 11):

you probably want to quote 'news' as a string... 
You also probably want to use an inner join instead (much more efficient)

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.id 
WHERE table1.content = 'news' 
AND table1.content_id = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

`news` is what? Some sort of parameter? Value of the field? A word which should occur in the field? Most likely your syntax is wrong, see [W3Schools WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_where.asp) and [W3Schools AND/OR](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) operators pages for more information.

Answer (score 3):

let me rewrite that for you with a JOIN statement since it is not 1995 anymore, you also need quotes around news

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.user_id = t2.id
AND t1.content = 'news'
AND t1.content_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

- What do table1 and table2 look like? Can you paste a create script?
- I would *STRONGLY* recommend to use the proper JOIN syntax:

  select * from table1
  inner join table2 on table1.user_id = table2.id
  ......
- what datatypes is "table1.content" ?

You can most definitely have a lot more than just 2 AND statements in a SQL query - any database that really support any of the SQL-xx standards will support this...

Answer (score 1):

First let's start with getting rid of that old-style join so that the join and where clauses are clearly separated to make understanding much easier.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1.
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.user_id = t2.id
WHERE t1.content = news
AND t1.content_id = 1
```

Now let's discuss what the problem might be. First what error are you receiving as this could be perfectly acceptable syntax? Could the problem be that you have not noted which table news is to come from? If it is in both tables you could be getting an error there. If news is meant to be the value of the column you would want it to be 'news' instead of news. It could also simply be that no records meet your conditions.

Further it is a bad practice to ever use select * and it should never be used in a join as you are returning at least one field twice and that is wasteful of both database and network resources. Always specify only the columns you need. This wastes lots of resources every day when lazy programmers do this in every query.

Answer (score 0):

I liked cmartin's response. Also, you can use more than one AND, if needed.